# función isloggedin en React

Tags: reactjs

estoy comenzando a aprender y practicar en React, mi idea era hacer una pantalla de inicio de sesión, en donde llamo a un api rest y almaceno en memoria el usuario, al iniciar sesión redirijo a una Home al usuario. El problema está en que quiero que si el usuario está logueado, no vea la pantalla de inicio de sesión. Para ello, le envío el state "isLogged" al componente "login" y si el usuario tiene el state "Logueado" quiero redirigirlo. El problema es qu no está llegando el state correctamente:

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css';
import Login from './Pages/Login/Login'
import Logout from './Pages/Logout/Logout'
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home'


export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: "no-logueado",
      user:{},
    };

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
    this.loggedIn = this.loggedIn.bind(this);  

  }

  handleLogin(data){
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: "Logueado",
      user: data
    });
  }

  handleLogout(){
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: "no-logueado",
      user: {}
    });
  }

  isLoggedin(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
    if(this.state.loggedIn === "no-logueado" && token){
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: "Logueado",
        user: token
      });
    }
  }

  loggedIn(data){
    if(data === "Logueado"){
      window.location="/home";
    }
  }

async componentDidMount(){
  await this.isLoggedin();
}

  render() {
    
      return (
        <Router>
          <Route exact path="/" render={props => ( <Login {... props} handleLogin={this.handleLogin} loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn}/>)} />
          <Route exact path="/logout" render={props => ( <Logout {... props} handleLogout={this.handleLogout}/>)} />
          <Route exact path="/home" render={props => (<Home {... props} loggedIn={this.loggedIn} log={this.state.loggedIn}/>)} />


          <script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

          <script
            src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
            crossorigin></script>

          <script
            src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js"
            crossorigin></script>

          <script>var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;</script>
        </Router>
      );
  }
}
```

Login

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Input from './Components/Input/input'
import Label from './Components/Label/Label'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './Login.css'
import {Container, Row, Col, Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user:' ',
            password:' '
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleSuccessfullAuth = this.handleSuccessfullAuth.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(name, value) {
        if(name==='username'){
            this.setState({user:value});
        } else {
            this.setState({password:value});
        }
    }

    async handleSubmit(){

            const requestOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    body: JSON.stringify({ 
                        email: this.state.user,
                        password:this.state.password
                    })
            };
            
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', requestOptions);
            console.log(response.ok);
            if(response.ok){
                const res = await response.json();
                localStorage.setItem("authToken", res.token)
                this.handleSuccessfullAuth(res);
            } else {
                console.log("token", localStorage.getItem("authToken"))
            }
             
        }

        handleSuccessfullAuth(data){
            this.props.handleLogin(data);
            this.props.history.push("/home");
        }
    
        componentDidMount(){
            console.log(this.props.loggedIn)
        }

    render(){
        return (       
            <div id="login-background">
                <Container>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={6}>
                            <Col xs={8}  className="back">
                                <h2 className="tittle-login">¡ Bienvenido !</h2>
                                <h2 className="tittle-login">{this.props.loggedIn}</h2>
                                <hr className="hr-design"></hr>
                            <Label text='Usuario'/>
                            <Input attribute= {{
                                id: 'username',
                                name:'username',
                                type:'text',
                                placeholder:'Ingrese su usuario ...',
                                className:'form-control'
                            }}
                            handleChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                            <Label text='Contraseña'/>
                            <Input attribute= {{
                                id: 'password',
                                name:'password',
                                type:'password',
                                placeholder:'Ingrese su contraseña ...',
                                className:'form-control'
                            }}
                            handleChange={this.handleChange}
                            /><br></br>
                            <Button variant="primary" size="lg" block onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Iniciar Sesión</Button>{' '}
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs={4}>

                            </Col>
                                
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                        
                        </Col>
                            
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Cuando veo por consola como llega el estado a "login" llega como "no logueado" aunque en la pantalla me renderiza "logueado".

Me podrían ayudar? Creo que me está faltando aprender o relacionar algo. Gracias!

[Renderiza logueado, pero por consola veo no logueado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t42OE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas esta función:

```
isLoggedin(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
    if(this.state.loggedIn === "no-logueado" && token){
      this.setState({
        loggedIn: "Logueado",
        user: token
      });
    }
  }
```

`this.state.loggedIn` es "Logueado" cuando `authToken` existe. La pantalla de inicio de sesión cambia porque `render()` cambia dos veces.
Puedes verlo si escribes

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.loggedIn)
    ....
```

`componentDidMount()` solo muestra el valor del primer render.
Si quieres el valor del ultimo render puedes usar `componentDidUpdate()`.
Puedes leer más sobre componentDidUpdate() [aquí](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!

En este caso, lo que quise poner en el condicional es: Si el estado loggedIn es "no-logueado" y además existe un token (el token es información de usuario, no contiene el string logueado), entonces cambia el estado a "Logueado" y el usuario lo rellena con el token.

En pantalla, se muestra Logueado correctamente, pero lo que me hace falta es porque cuando envío dicho estado a otro componente, va como "no-logueado" y no con el estado cambiado teniendo en cuenta que existe un token.

Se entiende mi problema? 
Gracias!!

Comment: Lo siento, entendí mal. Actualice la respuesta.

Comment: Esto es exactamente lo que me faltaba entender. Ya logré realizar la redirección dependiendo del estado de la sesión como correspondia.
Muchas gracias!